# SQL Server Integration Services 2016 error, cannot bulk load XML file

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

My SSIS package fails on "Execute SQL Talk" which executes a stored procedure trying to load XML file. I get the following error:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "exec [dbo].[AccuplacerXMLProcessing] ?" failed with the following error: "Cannot bulk load. The file "J:\Accuplacer\000753-001\16209412.xml" does not exist.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

However, when I execute the same stored procedure in SSMS when connected as the same user it succeeds.

[image: See screenshot]

Both SQL Server Agent job and execution via SSMS were done by the same Windows domain user. This user has bulkadmin role on the server.

File is located on the server where the job is running.

There should not be any issues accessing the file. I've spent all day staring at this and cannot figure it out.

Comment: Sounds like the agent accont doesn't have access.

Answer (score 0):

`J:\Accuplacer\000753-001\16209412.xml" does not exist`

Either the file is not there or the user does not have access to it on some level.

I noticed that the file name in your error is different than in your screen shot.